# Why severely increased Ligand (eg Hormones) concentration downregulates the Receptor?

Tags: biochemistry, human-physiology, endocrinology

As an example continuous high blood level of GnRH in humans causes a suppression of LH and FSH. This is due to the fact that increased GnRH downregulates **GnRH-Receptors** . My question is how this is done and why? What are the probable molecular mechanisms underlying this effect?

> Kumar P, Sharma A. Gonadotropin-releasing hormone analogs:
> Understanding advantages and limitations. J Hum Reprod Sci.
> 2014;7(3):170-174. doi:10.4103/0974-1208.142476
> https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4229791/

Comment: Hi A.N. Ψ, Could you provide more resources on continuous high blood level of GnRH in humans causes a suppression of LH and FSH? Or on the fact that increased GnRH downregulates GnRH-Receptors?

Comment: Go through the paper. I have added it to the Question

Answer (score 1):

Gonadotropins are hormones synthesized and released by the *[anterior pituitary gland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anterior_pituitary)*, which act on the testes and ovaries to increase the production of sex hormones and stimulate production of either sperm or ova.

The hypothalamus contains Gonadotropin-[releasing hormone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Releasing_and_inhibiting_hormones) (GnRH). Intermittent released of GnRH is responsible for the biosynthesis and secretion of follicle-stimulating hormone (FSH) and luteinizing hormone (LH) from the [anterior pituitary gland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anterior_pituitary).

LH stimulates interstitial cells to release testosterone, which triggers spermatogenesis. The rising level of testosterone exerts negative feedback control on the hypothalamus and pituitary glands.

*GnRH has been shown here in a negative feedback loop*

This feedback loop has great interplay with the number receptor levels as you suggest.

(From a quick search) I found [one paper](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/10467232/) (behind a paywall) that states the following information when studying rats:

> We observed an acute reduction of both GnRH and GnRH-R mRNAs 24 h after the injection [of GnRH agonist (triptorelin)] (about 38% of control).

Transcription does not equal translation, but it seems that acute increased levels of GnRH cause a reduction and mRNA of GnRH and GnRH-R and therefore potential reduction (down-regulation) of protein levels of GnRH-R.